# Export selected layer from Photoshop to web format

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I have this big PSD file (300MB) which I need to somehow, export each layer as a web format (PNG for example) to fit them in a HTML. The only thing I found in PS is in the Scripts menu, the Export Layers to File option, but it takes forever and it doesn't even save all layers. I also like them to be exported in a directory hierarchy, like they're in PS, but this is optional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following points can help you :

1. http://software.metadma.com/LayerSplitter.html . Allows you to save the layers . But it is not free. It saves in directories.

2.you can  have only those relevant layer(s) that you want to export visible. (So hide all the layers that you don't want to export and keep the relevant one's visible.) Then go to File - Save for web and save your image.

3. Alternatively you can run this [script](http://www.mediafire.com/?jdrflshvx1zaswt).